# Telerik Test Studio - Web Test New Tab

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, telerik, telerik-test-studio

I'm working with Telerik Test Studio for my c# Silverlight application that runs on a SharePoint server. The current issue I'm running into is that a recorded test doesn't continue executing if I hit a button that opens up a new tab where I'd like the test to continue. The context for the steps stays in the tab that opened the new one.

I'm able to record steps for the new tab by simply selecting it from the Record drop down, but when the test is run, it doesn't recognize and attach to the new tab after it's opened by the previous step.

Anyone know how to get Telerk Test Studio to run test steps in a tab other than the one it was started in?

I do not have the option to simply redirect from the original page.

Comment: If  your new tab contains auto-generated text, you can remove this text. For reference:   `https://www.telerik.com/videos/teststudio/how-to-automate-html-popups---test-studio-workshop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that Test Studio does not support tabbed browsing. [As documented here](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/configure-your-browser/internet-explorer.aspx) (go to the "Pop-ups Open in a New Window" section) you must disable tabbed browsing, force popups to open in a new browser window instead. Then your test will work as intended.

Cody
Test Studio Senior Support Officer